# Values ​are not entered in the spinner

Tags: java, android

Hello the code below shows a spinner in an activity my problem is that the dropdown does not work, only the 1 element of the array is displayed. 
In the spinner, only the first element inserted in the arraylist is displayed. What can this be due to? I state that I am using this code in other activities and it does not give me any problems

**Layout XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".View.ComponentiCantiere.CreazioneCantiereActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include3"
        layout="@layout/content_creazione_cantiere"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include3"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="left|top" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSelezionaCliente"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/clienti" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNuovoCantiere"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nuovo_cantiere"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewCreazioneCantiere"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:text="Creazione Cantiere"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSelezioneCliente"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
        android:text="Seleziona cliente"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTipologia"
        android:layout_width="81dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Tipologia:"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnertipologiacantiere"
        android:layout_width="153dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@color/Gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_NomeCantiere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="Nome Cantiere:"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editextNomeCantiere"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="@color/Gray" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
public class CreazioneCantiereActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txtNomeCantiere;
    private String TipologiaCantiereSelezionato="Consuntivo";
    private Button btnCreaCantiere, btnSelezionacliente;
    private ClienteController c;
    private Spinner spinnerTipologie;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_creazione_cantiere);
        //Intent che contiene il cliente e l'utente
        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        final UtenteController u = (UtenteController) i.getSerializableExtra("UtenteController");
        c = (ClienteController) i.getSerializableExtra("ClienteController");
        btnCreaCantiere = findViewById(R.id.buttonNuovoCantiere);
        btnSelezionacliente = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelezionaCliente);
        txtNomeCantiere = findViewById(R.id.editextNomeCantiere);
        //Inizializzazione spinner tipologie cantiere
        spinnerTipologie = findViewById(R.id.spinnertipologiacantiere);
        spinnerTipologie.setEnabled(true);
        //Inizio Configurazione Spinner delle tipologia del cantiere con Consuntivo e Preventivo
        List<String> arraySpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraySpinner.add("Consuntivo");
        arraySpinner.add("Preventivo");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTipologie.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Configurazione Button Creazione CantiereController
        btnSelezionacliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent tab = new Intent(CreazioneCantiereActivity.this, ClienteActivity.class);
                tab.putExtra("UtenteController", u);
                tab.putExtra("Stato", "Selezione");
                startActivity(tab);
            }

        });


        //Configurazione Button Creazione CantiereController
        btnCreaCantiere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (txtNomeCantiere.getText().toString().length() > 0 && c != null) {
                    CantiereController ctemp = new CantiereController();
                    ArrayList readvalue = new ArrayList();
                    readvalue = ctemp.Creazione(txtNomeCantiere.getText().toString(), spinnerTipologie.getSelectedItem().toString(),u, c);
                    if (readvalue.isEmpty() == false) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CreazioneCantiereActivity.this, GestioneCantieriActivity.class);
                        ctemp = (CantiereController) readvalue.get(0);
                        intent.putExtra("CantiereController", ctemp);
                        intent.putExtra("UtenteController", u);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Support.Notification(CreazioneCantiereActivity.this, "Errore", "creazione cantiere non riuscita");
                    }
                } else {
                    Support.Notification(CreazioneCantiereActivity.this, "Errore", "compila tutti i campi");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your activity layout file as well?

Comment: I have add layout file @Jarvis

Answer (score 0):

So you wanna create an static array and show in your spinner? Tell me if the code bellow helps you:

activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/booksSpinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/books_array"/>
```

strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="books_array">
     <item>Hamlet</item>
     <item>Harry Potter</item>
     <item>The Great Gatsby</item>
</string-array>
```

Doing that, you will remove the responsibility for creating the array of your java class and just needs to get the spinner value in onCreate() method. Example:

```
findViewById (R.id.booksSpinner);
```

**EDIT 1:**

You said that did not work but i tested and it worked. Check the full code:

ActivityMain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="313dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Spinner test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.148"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.032"  />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnertipologiacantiere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:ems="10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainLabel"
        android:entries="@array/books_array"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinnerTipologie;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinnerTipologie = findViewById(R.id.spinnertipologiacantiere);

    }

}
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApplication</string>

    <string-array name="books_array">
        <item>Hamlet</item>
        <item>Harry Potter</item>
        <item>The Great Gatsby</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Hello, again! I added more books in my books_array of strings.xml to test the scroll and it worked as you can see bellow:

```
<string-array name="books_array">
        <item>Hamlet</item>
        <item>Harry Potter</item>
        <item>The Great Gatsby</item>
        <item>Don Quixote</item>
        <item>Moby Dick</item>
        <item>War and Peace</item>
        <item>Ulysses</item>
        <item>The Odyssey</item>
        <item>Beloved</item>
        <item>The Hobbit</item>
        <item>Les Misérables</item>
        <item>The Magic Mountain</item>
        <item>The Lord of the Rings</item>
        <item>Animal Farm</item>
        <item>The Castle</item>
    </string-array>
```

[image]

If you are using my code correctly, your spinner should work. Maybe there is something missing for you, I suggest you edit your post and add your updated code so I can understand what is happening

Comment: Hello. Can you tell me what happened?

Comment: the scroll of spinner not work, I see only first element of array